# SharePoint Server: when to use -CopyEvents with Move-SPSite?

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, move

When moving site collections with Move-SPSite, there is a parameter called -CopyEvents. The [documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spsite?view=sharepoint-server-ps):

> Specifies if events of the EventCache table need to be copied to the destination Content Database.

When would I want/need to use that?

Note: The EventCache table is described by [this old Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb417456(v=office.14)) as *"Every content database contains an EventCache table that is the "change log" for objects contained in the database."*

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 1):

The EventCache table can be checkd in the SQL server.

The EventCache table is used to record all audit logs in a site collection. Each row in the table depictes a change in an object. Columns in the table contain information such as the date and time of a change, the type of object that was changed, the nature of the change, and a unique identifier for the object. Such as: "A list item is added" and so on.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Brilliant, thank you @Emily Du - MSFT. So the feature should really have been named "-CopyAuditEvents" for clarity. :)